# How to toggle vim settings

Tags: vim

I will sometimes use vim commands like ':set lbr' or ':set spell'.  But how do I turn them off after they've been activated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prepend `no` to boolean options to turn them off.

```
:set nolbr
```

You can also append `!` to boolean options to toggle them.

```
:set lbr!
```

You might combine this with appending a `?` to display the current value after toggling:

```
:set lbr! lbr?
```

Comment: Great suggestion for displaying the current value after toggling...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
:set nolbr
```

or

```
:set nospell
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do them as one word,

`:set nolbr`

and 
`:set nospell`.

You can also toggle with an exclamation point:

`:set lbr!`

will turn it on if it's off, and off it's on.

See `:help :set` for even more options.

Answer (score -1):

try

> :set no lbr

or

> :set no spell

Comment: It returns E518: Unknown option: no

Comment: What version of vim does this work in? I type it all the time!